# Java logical || with compareToIgnoreCase

Tags: java

In my program I use this if statement:

```
final String single = "single";
final String married = "married";
//status is equal to what the user inputted, also a string
if((status.compareToIgnoreCase(single) != 0) || (status.compareToIgnoreCase(married) != 0)){
        System.out.println("Does not equate");
    }
```

to figure out what the user input. When status is changed to "single", or "SINGLE", the program returns "Does not equate". Why is it displaying the "does not equate" line when the status is equal?

Comment: `single` != `married`...one of those conditions HAS to fail...And I would think `String#equalsIgnoreCase` would be simpler...

Comment: when status is "single" the `...IgnoreCase(married)` fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition is mutually exclusive.  One of the two conditions always be true.  ie:  if status is married, then it is not single.  If status is single, then it is not married.

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to test, but a more likely condition would be:

```
if((!status.equalsIgnoreCase(single) && (!status.equalsToIgnoreCase(married))){
        System.out.println("Does not equate");
    }
```

Comment: Oh... thanks! I was looking at it through a different point of view

Comment: I guess I needed to brush up on my logic- thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your logical or causes the expression to always be `true`, you need a logical `and`

```
if ((status.compareToIgnoreCase(single) != 0) && 
    (status.compareToIgnoreCase(married) != 0))
```

**or**, you can apply a DeMorgan transform and get

```
if ((status.compareToIgnoreCase(single) == 0) || 
    (status.compareToIgnoreCase(married) == 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

A good reference for truth tables when using logical operators.
http://kias.dyndns.org/comath/21.html
Eric B.'s answer was good I just couldn't comment on his.